# I have a bad feeling about this country name

Tags: word, no-computers

What is the longest country name  that can be fully anagramed into one word from the Merriam-Webster dictionary?

Please use [this site](https://www.worldometers.info/geography/alphabetical-list-of-countries/) for the list of countries.

Minimum length 8 letters. If a country has 2 or more words in its name, then all the letters from those words must anagram to one single word. It is obvious, but if a country name has n letters the anagramed word must also have exactly n letters.

Please no programming. Don't forget to consider the title.

Comment: for Congo, Czechia, Eswatini, and Myanmar, are we allowed to use the name versions in parentheses?

Comment: Yes indeed. But remember 8 letters minimum

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given the title, I think the answer is

> **Micronesia**

which anagrams to

> [Acrimonies](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acrimony#:%7E:text=%3A%20anger%20and%20bitterness%20%3A%20harsh%20or,dispute%20continued%20with%20increased%20acrimony.), which means feelings of anger or bitterness

Answer (score 2):

The longest I could find was

> San Marino -> Romanians.

However, I am unsure of two things:

> 1) There is a possibility that the website I used to search for anagrams (Quinapalus Word Matcher) does not have complete results. I may have missed some equally valid and longer options.
>
>  2) Technically, "Romanians" does not have an entry in the current free online Merriam-Webster dictionary, but "Romanian" does. However, Romanians can be a valid plural form for Romanian, and typing Romanians into the dictionary redirects me to the entry for Romanian.

Methodology:

> I'm not good at programming anyway, so I resorted to brute force (bad news: tedious; good news: I had time).
>
>  First, I copy-pasted part of the table in the site provided by OP. Next, I removed all the numbers and spaces, and then proceeded to sort them all by length, by hand. (Again, the downsides of not having a programmer's knowledge, but at least I wasn't breaking any rules set by OP! :P )
>  It was also fortunate that OP reminded me that only countries of length 8 letters or more are to be considered, so in the middle of sorting I removed the countries with less than 8 letters as well. Finally, I entered, one-by-one, each country name into the Quinapalus Word Matcher site.

At this point,

> No anagrams of countries with length 10 letters or more appeared. After that, I saw Argentina -> "tanagrine", and San Marino -> "Romanians". Quick searches in Merriam-Webster (free online version) invalidated the first result.

Comment: And unfortunately, it doesn't explain the title either...